# Multiple Form Submit - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have my **edit.blade.php** file as below mentioned

```
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Vendor</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Rate</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Job No</th>
                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($po_items as $po_item)
                        <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="vendor_name[]" id="vendor_name" value="{{$po_item->cost_item->vendor_company->name}}" readonly></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_name[]" id="item_name" value="{{$po_item->cost_item->item->name}}" readonly></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty[]" id="qty" value="{{$po_item->qty}}"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="rate[]" id="rate" value="{{$po_item->rate}}"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="total[]" id="total" value="{{$po_item->qty * $po_item->rate}}"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" id="description" value="{{$po_item->description}}"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="job_id[]" id="job_id" value="{{$po_item->cost_item->job_id}}" readonly></td>
                                <td>
                                    <form action="{{action('Employee\POItemController@destroy', $po_item->id)}}" method="post">
                                            {{csrf_field()}}
                                            {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>                          
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach 
                </tbody>


            </table>




            <form action="{{ route('employee.poitem.update', $vendor_company_id )}}" method="post">            
                {{csrf_field()}}
                {{method_field('PATCH')}}
                @foreach ($po_items as $po_item)
                    <input type="hidden" name="cost_item_id[]"  value="?">
                    <input type="hidden" name="qty[]" value="?">
                    <input type="hidden" name="rate[]" value="?">
                    <input type="hidden" name="description[]" value="?">
                    @endforeach          


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            </form>
```

Since there are two forms in the same page, i find it hard to pass new form values to the **update function**. I read on using the same session to solve this issue, but it wasn't clear enough for me to proceed with it

Comment: Can you be more clear on problem? Are you unable to post update value in controller?Is first and second form related to each other?

Comment: 1 form is for update, Many others are for destroy. So they can't be mixed. Unless you define an update_destroy route.

Comment: @SundarBan Yes. I am unable to post update value in controller because the of the delete form. Second form is there because i am unable to pass the values from the first form

Comment: @KeitelDOG forms are not mixed(not Nested). But i am unable to pass new values to update the database

Comment: @zaster I can clearly see that there is a nested form.

Comment: @Pankaj I am very sorry about that. Corrected it now.

Comment: If you only want to delete the row data, You don't need to use Form, you can only use anchor tag.

Comment: Ohh ok. I finally understand your problem. I was in a rush yesterday. So because you opened the form before the `@foreach` you need each po_item values to be added in their corresponding input array? But are qty, cost_item_id, rate are filled from po_item attribute directly? I'll answer when I get home

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Making delete form you can do it with anchor tag. I don't know it is correct way or not but it works fine.

```
<a href="{{action('Employee\POItemController@destroy', $po_item->id)}}">Delete</a>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: As per my knowledge using a get request to delete a record is not a good practice

Comment: This will probably fail because the Route is surely declared as POST. Route not found Exception.

Comment: It works fine if your route has get method if we use anchor tag, and in laravel for delete there is delete method @KeitelDOG

Comment: Writing data in database for direct user inputs require POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE request methods. GET method is not allowed at all, that's why I said it will fail. Only indirect data writing is allowed with GET like page views incrementation, or other stats or fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your input id values are incorrect. In HTML, an id should be unique across all HTML tags. When you make a foreach :

```
@foreach ($po_items as $po_item)
<tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="vendor_name[]" id="vendor_name" value="{{$po_item->cost_item->vendor_company->name}}" readonly></td>                         
</tr>
@endforeach
```

you're assigning all inputs vendor_name to same `id="vendor_name`, which is W3C incorrect. You could use instead

```
@foreach ($po_items as $po_item)
<tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="vendor_name[]" id="vendor_name_{{$po_item->id}}" value="{{$po_item->cost_item->vendor_company->name}}" readonly></td>                         
</tr>
@endforeach
```

But that's not the real problem here, you need upon submitting the UPDATE Form to read each input data and pushes it in hidden inputs.

Do you use vanilla Javascript or JQuery? With JQuery you can achieve it easier, you must put some scripts on the page that contains the forms. The idea is to find each input value for like qty, push them into array and convert that array to JSON string and put that JSON string as value to hidden qty input. Try this codes :

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Vendor</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Job No</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_inputs">
        @foreach ($po_items as $po_item)
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="vendor_name[]" id="vendor_name_{{$po_item->id}}" value="{{$po_item->cost_item->vendor_company->name}}" readonly></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_name[]" id="item_name_{{$po_item->id}}" value="{{$po_item->cost_item->item->name}}" readonly></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty[]" id="qty_{{$po_item->id}}" value="{{$po_item->qty}}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="rate[]" id="rate_{{$po_item->id}}" value="{{$po_item->rate}}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="total[]" id="total_{{$po_item->id}}" value="{{$po_item->qty * $po_item->rate}}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" id="description_{{$po_item->id}}" value="{{$po_item->description}}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="job_id[]" id="job_id_{{$po_item->id}}" value="{{$po_item->cost_item->job_id}}" readonly></td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{{action('Employee\POItemController@destroy', $po_item->id)}}" method="post">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>

</table>


<form id="form_update_poitem" action="{{ route('employee.poitem.update', $vendor_company_id )}}" method="post">            
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('PATCH')}}
    @foreach ($po_items as $po_item)
        <input type="hidden" name="cost_item_id[]" >
        <input type="hidden" name="qty[]" >
        <input type="hidden" name="rate[]" >
        <input type="hidden" name="description[]" >
    @endforeach
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log('document is ready, proceed to form update codes');

    // find button form
    var button = $('#form_update_poitem button');

    // add onclick event
    button.on('click', function(e){
        // find input array input values, turn them into array and pass that array to Hidden Input array
        var itemArr = [];
        $("#table_inputs input[type='item_name']").each(function(){
            itemArr.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(itemArr);
        $("#form_update_poitem input[type='cost_item_name']").val(JSON.stringify(itemArr));

        var qtyArr = [];
        $("#table_inputs input[type='qty']").each(function(){
            qtyArr.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(qtyArr);
        $("#form_update_poitem input[type='qty']").val(JSON.stringify(qtyArr));

        var rateArr = [];
        $("#table_inputs input[type='rate']").each(function(){
            rateArr.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(rateArr);
        $("#form_update_poitem input[type='rate']").val(JSON.stringify(rateArr));

        var descriptionArr = [];
        $("#table_inputs input[type='description']").each(function(){
            descriptionArr.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(descriptionArr);
        $("#form_update_poitem input[type='description']").val(JSON.stringify(descriptionArr));

    });

});

</script>
```